# cast class to SensorEventListener

Tags: android, clojure, clojure-java-interop

I'm trying to register `SensorEventListener` but my listener has wrong type.

Here's what I tried:

```
;; listener
(gen-class
:name com.spython.pushupcounter.main.sensor-listener
:implements [android.hardware.SensorEventListener]
:prefix "-"
:methods [[onAccuracyChanged [android.hardware.Sensor Integer] void]
                    [onSensorChanged [android.hardware.SensorEvent] void]])

(def listener com.spython.pushupcounter.main.sensor-listener)
(.registerListener sensor-manager listener proximitySensor 2)
```

Looks like I need to cast `listener` to `SensorEventListener`, right?
How can I do this?

Comment: What's the error you're seeing?  You might need to add a [type hint](http://clojure.org/java_interop#Java%20Interop-Type%20Hints): `(.registerListener sensor-manager ^SensorEventListener listener proximitySensor 2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symbols matching a class name, like `com.spython.pushupcounter.main.sensor-listener` resolve to instances of `java.lang.Class`. So your `listener` is a `Class`, which is not what you want. It should be instead an instance of `com.spython.pushupcounter.main.sensor-listener`. Instances can be created using standard instantiation syntax `(com.spython.pushupcounter.main.sensor-listener.)` - note a `.` at the end - syntax sugar for `new`. But even after you fix this, the code won't work. `(gen-class)` is tricky to use this way. It only generates the class if AOT compilation is used and does nothing otherwise. You also have to provide the implementation for `SensorEventListener` methods.

A better approach is to use `(reify)`, which returns an object that implements desired interface(s). For example:

```
(defn listener []
  (reify
    android.hardware.SensorEventListener
    (onAccuracyChanged [_ sensor accuracy] 
      (comment onAccuracyChanged implementation here))
    (onSensorChanged [_ event]
      (comment onSensorChanged implementation here))))

(.registerListener sensor-manager (listener) proximitySensor 2)
```

Comment: You helped me second time in a row!

Comment: @SPython Is it possible that you share the working source code?

Comment: @Brian Back then I ended up writting it in pure Java (I had some problems with clojure-neko)... I have the source code, but it's not Clojure.

Comment: @SPython Okay! Thanks for the ultra-quick response!